# Problem executing stored procedure in my code

Tags: c++, sql-server, ssms, c++builder

I had a stored procedure that returns a set of 8 `integer` values. At the beginning all seems to be executed in the right way but after some execution when I execute it in my C++ code using `TADOQuery` the execution time grows up but not in the SSMS in which the execution time still correct.

In a first step I try to evolve my stored procedure to make it more performance aware. I earned some execution time but the problem still present.

I try also to examine my code searching some absurd lines that may extend execution time. But I use the same code with other stored procedures and they don't show the same effect.

So I use the SQL Profiler to see what the hell is going on. Below you can see the differences between a good execution and a bad one.

**Good execution**

```
 CPU | Reads | Writes | Duration 
 93  | 13657 | 0      | 113
```

**Bad execution**

```
 CPU      | Reads    | Writes | Duration
 22090    | 31960629 | 0      | 25158
```

As you can see the values of reads and CPU access grows exponentially.

If I execute the same stored procedure in the SSMS query editor, the results are straight forward to the good execution.

I just want that my stored procedure were executed always with more or less the same duration regardless where I execute the query.

Comment: As to why you are apparently getting different execution plans, [see this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Also see [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the execution plan.

When the stored procedure is compiled, a new plan based on actual data is determined. After a few executions the plan get to old because the data change frequently.

So to achieve this problem I used the WITH RECOMPILE options for the stored procedure. I think it's not the best solution but it solves the problem and now I don't have the query timeout anymore.

In this way I try some other solutions to apply the recompile in the best moment but the only solution that works well is with this option.

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this several times - it catches a lot of us.  Check the settings against your call for things like ansi nulls on/off, other settings etc.  Changes like that lead to different execution plans.  See 
[SQL faster in ssms than in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526087/sql-faster-in-ssms-than-in-application/53536961#53536961) for details.

Comment: In fact if I execute an update statistics against the tables involved, the execution time return normal (between 100ms and 250ms)

Comment: Its all down to minor differences in the ways the calls are made. So long as you've got a working solution then thats great.  Accepting this as an answer will help other user identify what has worked for others in the past.

Comment: I had detected where the problem is. It's a statistics problem. When the store proc is executed the execution plan turned old after a few executions. So I modified my store procedure adding WITH RECOMPILE option. The plan is redefined every execution. It's a little tough solution but it works.